# Linux graphical alternative to WinSCP tunneled connection

Tags: linux, ssh, tunnel

Is there a Linux or multiplatform software with GUI that allows you to browse and download files from a server behind a SSH tunnel ([this is a winscp example](http://intranet.cs.hku.hk/csintranet/contents/technical/howto/winscp.jsp))?

```
|client|----ssh----|gateway|-----ssh-----|target_host|
   |                                         |
   +------------WinSCP alternative-----------+
```

**UPDATE**

To clarify, there are 3 systems involved. A local one (`client`) and 2 remote:

- The first one, which I called `gateway` is accessible via ssh from the internet. But it doesn't have the files I want.
- The second one, which I called `target_host` is accessible from `gateway` but not directly from the Internet

I want to graphically browse the `target_host`, and I have done so using WinSCP, that allows me to establish a ssh tunnel to `gateway` and then connect to `target_host`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's very common for file transfer software to address this use case, so it's interesting that WinSCP has it. Unless someone else knows of other software that does this, you'll probably have to do the tunnel setup yourself. This should help:

[An SSH tunnel via multiple hops](https://superuser.com/questions/96489/ssh-tunnel-via-multiple-hops)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at SecureFX. Assuming you are running locally, and needing to copy files from remote server A to remote server B, it may require a daisy chain of downloading to your local computer and then uploading to the second server... but the tabbed interface allowing multiple connections simultaneously may help speed things up for you.

Comment: My problem is that I cannot connect directly to the second server, I can only reach it through the first one.

Answer (score -1):

I was not able to comment (not +50 yet) so here's a response.  I am not sure I understand your question either.  It sounds like you want a GUI to be able to copy files back and forth with the destination server accessed via ssh.

winscp and filezilla client both work fine for windows.  Since you are looking for multi-platform and winscp does not work on windows, I would say go with filezilla client.  By default it will use ftp port 21.  Just enter port 22 and it will use sftp/scp

I'm guessing I misundestand your question too, but that is what it sounds like you're asking (?)

Comment: I'll update the question :)

Comment: Oh dang :) Okay if I had read it more closely and looked more closely at your link, I think I would have gotten it.  Okay yeah, filezilla does not do tunneling.  I haven't done anything like this before.  However, I have just been looking at ssh tunneling and found a link on superuser which shows how to set up ssh tunnel.  From there perhaps you can use filezilla after you've set up your ssh tunnel?

Comment: Link: [link]http://superuser.com/questions/62303/how-can-i-tunnel-all-of-my-network-traffic-through-ssh[/link]