# How to browser privately in Firefox and Chrome over login & password?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, privacy

I'd like to open a web browser, login to it with my details so my cookies and all the history/stuff is stored only somewhere in Cloud. I haven't found this solution so far. Maybe I am not looking  closely enough. There are a lot of privacy addons but I need something that will make my browsing really private, and really only mine :-)

How can I achieve this in Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: Absolute privacy is never reached.

Comment: I do not care about absolute privacy. I want CLOUD privacy upon login and password, I don't want anything saved on my work pc :)

Comment: You can't say you want total privacy if you want to store your data to the cloud. Cloud = someone else's computer/network.

Comment: Please get back to my question :P I didn't use TOTAL or ABSOLUTE words

Comment: @Greenleader [Private Browsing](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/private-browsing-browse-web-without-saving-info) mode on Firefox does what you want. You'll also want to take a look into [tunneling your traffic through SSH](http://superuser.com/questions/62303/how-can-i-tunnel-all-of-my-network-traffic-through-ssh). Bypassing your work's firewall restrictions is _never_ a good idea.

Comment: @happy_soil I am not planning to bypass work's firewall. + the tunnelling discusses linux and mac :-( I use Windows

Comment: Am I missing something? I asked for login-based browser and I get all these tunneling advices :)